# Angular How to prevent manual entry in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angular, autocomplete, angular-material, angular8

How to prevent manual entry in angular dropdown?

For example
my search dropdown value is like RAM, RAJ, KIRI, GURU..... and so on
and it has the id value of 1, 2, 3, 4..... and so on

my problem is if I type in input value for search. It must be not to accept the manual type search entry value if I click submit. How to do that? help me to solve it

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input placeholder="Select type" matInput formControlName="e_id"
    [matAutocomplete]="cotype">
      <mat-autocomplete #cotype="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
        <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading">Loading...</mat-option>
         <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let e of ceList" [value]="e.id">{{e.name}}</mat-option>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You can check if the input entered in the text box is present in the array `ceList` and enable/disable the submit button based on that?

Comment: Yes I tried like these methods but I taking more lines to solve this problem..

Comment: I don't think it would. If you can replicate the issue in a stackblitz, I could take a look.

Comment: yes sure.. please wait for some time ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach is to pass object as value to `mat-option`

```html
<mat-option *ngFor="let e of ceList" [value]="e">{{e.name}}</mat-option>
```

then in your submit function simply check:

```js
public onSubmit(){
  if(typeof  this.form.value.e_id === 'object') {
  //it's an object, manual entry will be string 

  } else {
   alert('Choose option from the list, manual entry not allowed!);

  }
}
```

In your `displayFn`, you can then process the value from object i.e

```js
displayFn(e_id){
 return e_id.id;
}
```

**Second Approach**
You can also create a custom validator and then pass it to your input, that way your form will not be valid unless value is selected:

```js
 private ceListSelectionValidator(fc: FormControl) {
    if (typeof fc.value === 'string') {
      return { incorrectValue: `Selected value '${fc.value}' is not from list` }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Pass this validator to your input during form creation:

```js
 this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
      e_id: ['', this.ceListSelectionValidator]
    });
```

and in your html, display the error to user:

```html
<span *ngIf="form.control.e_id.errors?.incorrectValue">
    {{form.control.e_id.errors?.incorrectValue}}
</span>
```

Comment: thank you for you ideas .. It is useful and working

Answer (score 2):

Try this way, It **solves your problem** also **simple** and **lightweight**.

```
      <ng-select [items]="ceList" 
                      placeholder="Select type"
                      class="form-control"
                      notFoundText="No  Found" 
                      bindLabel="name" 
                      bindValue="id" name="e_id"
                      [(ngModel)]="e_id">
       </ng-select>
```

Install: https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select